# How to use creds or any var from the azure library group in bash script

Tags: bash, azure, nexus

NEXUS IQ has two parameters for authentication instead of using a PAT. I have the usercode and passcode, along with the organizationid stored in a var group of my az pipeline. I'm using bash for my input script. I've drawn a blank regarding variable assignment to obtain the values stored in my az library group as I'm a bit rusty. HELP

```
#!/bin/bash

USERCODE=$1
PASSCODE=$2
ORGANIZATIONID=$3
NEWAPP=$4


# Check required values
if [ "$USERCODE" = "" ] || [ "$PASSCODE" = "" ] || [ "$ORGANIZATIONID" = "" ] || [ "$NEWAPP" = "" ]; then
   echo 'USERCODE, PASSCODE, ORG, NEWAPP cannot be empty values.'
   exit 1
fi


# create app
count=1
uri="https://nexusiq.xxxxxx.com/api/v2/applications"
raw=$(curl -u "${USERCODE}:${PASSCODE}" "${uri}?per_page=100&page=${count}")
while : ; do
  appname=$(echo $raw | jq '.[]|{name}' | jq -s '.')
   if [ appname == '' ]; then
      applicaions=$appname
      else
      applications=$(jq -s '.[0] + .[1]' <(echo $applications | jq '.') <(echo $appname | jq '.'))
   fi
((count++))
   raw=$(curl -u "${USERCODE}:${PASSCODE}" "${uri}?per_page=100&page=${count}")
   [ "$(echo $raw | jq -r '.|length')" == "0" ] && break
done
 if [[ ! ${applications[*]} =~ "$NEWAPP" ]]; #   
  JSON='{"organizationId":"'"$ORGANIZATIONID"'","publicId":"'"$NEWAPP"'","name":"'"$NEWAPP"'"}'
  curl -u "${USERCODE}:${PASSCODE}"-X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://nexusiq.xxxxx.com/api/v2/applications" -d $JSON
fi
```

Variables are not being initialized in script

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Problem: Required Variables were not being initialized for usercode and passcode to pull values from the az library group.